# Smack 4.2.0-beta1 Error in creating group chat 'MultiUserChat. Cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I am developing Chat application. I have done one to one chat. But I cannot create Group chat because it shows an below error

```
    'MultiUserChat(org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection, org.jxmpp.jid.EntityBareJid, org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChatManager)' is not public in 'org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat'. 
Cannot be accessed from outside package
```

I have seen some answers about creating groups everyone using `multiUserChat = new MultiUserChat(connection,room_name);` to create a Group chat.

But in 4.2.0-beta1 version is not allowing us to access this class.

I have added my code below

```
 public void createGroupChat() {
            // Create a MultiUserChat using a Connection for a room
    // (room name as the second parameter)
            try {
                Resourcepart nikname = Resourcepart.from("admin");

                MultiUserChat mMultiUserChat = new MultiUserChat(connection, "room@conference.myserver");
                mMultiUserChat.create(nikname);
                Form form = mMultiUserChat.getConfigurationForm().createAnswerForm();
                form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_publicroom", true);
                form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomname", "room");
                form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomowners", "owner");
                form.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_persistentroom", true);
                mMultiUserChat.sendConfigurationForm(form);
            } catch (XmppStringprepException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MultiUserChatException.MucAlreadyJoinedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MultiUserChatException.MissingMucCreationAcknowledgeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NotConnectedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MultiUserChatException.NotAMucServiceException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Can anyone tell me how to create group in Latest smack 4.2.0-beta1 version?

If I asked anything wrong sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found an answer to create group chat from this below link

https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/blob/master/documentation/extensions/muc.md

I have added my new code also. It can be helpful for some of other developers

```
 public void createGroupChat() {
        // Create a MultiUserChat using a Connection for a room
// Get the MultiUserChatManager
        MultiUserChatManager manager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
        try {
            EntityBareJid jid = JidCreate.entityBareFrom("myroom" + "@"
                    + context.getString(R.string.serviceNameOld));

// Create a MultiUserChat using an XMPPConnection for a room
            MultiUserChat muc = manager.getMultiUserChat(jid);

// Prepare a list of owners of the new room
            Set<Jid> owners = JidUtil.jidSetFrom(new String[]{"mathan@example.org", "kumar@example.org"});

// Create the room
            Resourcepart nickname = Resourcepart.from("mathan");
            muc.create(nickname).getConfigFormManager().setRoomOwners(owners).submitConfigurationForm();

        } catch (XmppStringprepException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MultiUserChatException.MucAlreadyJoinedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MultiUserChatException.MissingMucCreationAcknowledgeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NotConnectedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MultiUserChatException.NotAMucServiceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MultiUserChatException.MucConfigurationNotSupportedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You really should have used multi-catch here ;)

Comment: It gives me an warning message to add catch that's why I have added.  :( @Flow

Comment: I wrote that you should use multi-catch here, not that you should not catch the exception.

Comment: @Flow I am getting this below error  "The MUC configuration 'muc#roomconfig_roomowners' is not supported by the MUC service" Can you tell me how to solve this?